# Programmatically add new column to DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView bound to a DataTable. The DataTable is populated from a database query. The table contains a column named BestBefore. BestBefore is a date formatted as a string (SQLite doesn't have date types).

I would like to programmatically add a new column to the DataGridView called Status. If BestBefore is less than the current date, Status value should be set to OK, otherwise Status value should be set to NOT OK.

I'm very new to Winforms, so some example code would be greatly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

I think DataColumn.Expression is okay for doing simple calculations such multiplying a column's integer value by another value, but what about doing what I need to do? That is, calculate the difference between now and the date (string formatted) in the BestBefore column to determine what value to give the new status column. Example code would be appreciated.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Add new column to `DataTable` and use column `Expression` property to set your Status expression.

Here you can find good example: [`DataColumn.Expression` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx)

[DataTable and DataColumn Expressions in ADO.NET - Calculated Columns](http://davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2006/07/09/datacolumnexpressions.aspx)

**UPDATE**

Code sample:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("colBestBefore", typeof(DateTime)));
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("colStatus", typeof(string)));

dt.Columns["colStatus"].Expression = String.Format("IIF(colBestBefore < #{0}#, 'Ok','Not ok')", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));

dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1));
dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1));
dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(2));
dt.Rows.Add(DateTime.Now.AddDays(-2));

demoGridView.DataSource = dt;
```

**UPDATE #2**

```
dt.Columns["colStatus"].Expression = String.Format("IIF(CONVERT(colBestBefore, 'System.DateTime') < #{0}#, 'Ok','Not ok')", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: That's okay for simple expressions, but what about doing what I need to do? That is, calculate the difference between now and the date (string formatted) in the BestBefore column to determine what value to give the new status column. Example code would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @halfpint: i updated my answer with working sample of what you need.

Comment: My BestBefore column is a string formatted date and time not a DateTime type. Can this still be made to work? Thank you for your feedback - much appreciated.

Comment: @halfpint: yep, take a look at UPDATE #2.

Answer (score 49):

Keep it simple

```
dataGridView1.Columns.Add("newColumnName", "Column Name in Text");
```

To add rows

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Value for column#1"); // [,"column 2",...]
```

Answer (score 19):

Here's a sample method that adds two extra columns programmatically to the grid view:

```
    private void AddColumnsProgrammatically()
    {
        // I created these columns at function scope but if you want to access 
        // easily from other parts of your class, just move them to class scope.
        // E.g. Declare them outside of the function...
        var col3 = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        var col4 = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

        col3.HeaderText = "Column3";
        col3.Name = "Column3";

        col4.HeaderText = "Column4";
        col4.Name = "Column4";

        dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new DataGridViewColumn[] {col3,col4});
    }
```

A great way to figure out how to do this kind of process is to create a form, add a grid view control and add some columns. (This process will actually work for ANY kind of form control. All instantiation and initialization happens in the Designer.) Then examine the form's Designer.cs file to see how the construction takes place. (Visual Studio does everything programmatically but hides it in the Form Designer.)

For this example I created two columns for the view named Column1 and Column2 and then searched Form1.Designer.cs for Column1 to see everywhere it was referenced. The following information is what I gleaned and, copied and modified to create two more columns dynamically:

```
// Note that this info scattered throughout the designer but can easily collected.

        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn Column1;
        System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn Column2;

        this.Column1 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
        this.Column2 = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn();

        this.dataGridView1.Columns.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewColumn[] {
        this.Column1,
        this.Column2});

        this.Column1.HeaderText = "Column1";
        this.Column1.Name = "Column1";

        this.Column2.HeaderText = "Column2";
        this.Column2.Name = "Column2";
```

Comment: I don't want to just add a column. I want to set its value based on the value of another column with a date value.

Comment: after you add the column, in the DataBindingComplete event do something like this: `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows)
{if (row.Cells[7].Value.ToString()=="1")
row.Cells[0].Value = "number one"; }` (just an example..). But remember IT HAS to be in the DataBindingComplete, otherwise it'll remain blank

Comment: I like this answer because it doesn't need the additional DataTable defined.  This is the most clean and concise answer to solving this problem.  If I could award more than 1 vote I would.  Great answer...

Comment: +1  awesome! thanks for teaching me how to fish. The technique will be useful for learning many things about winforms

Comment: @JohnHenckel n/p That's what SO is all about. Also, thanks for the kind feedback!