# How can I manually add data to a dataGridView?

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I'm trying to run this code, and I get an exception:

> Index was out of range. Must be
>   non-negative and less than the size of
>   the collection. Parameter name: index

```
private void LoadStudentGrades(int gradeParaleloId, int subjectId)
{
    GradeStudentRepository gradeStudentRepo = new GradeStudentRepository();
    students = gradeStudentRepo.FindAllGradeStudents().Where(g => g.GradeParaleloId == gradeParaleloId)
                .Select(g => g.Student);

    int i = 1;
    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();

        row.Cells[0].Value = i.ToString();
        row.Cells[1].Value = student.LastNameFather + " " + student.LastNameMother + ", " + student.Name;

        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
        i++;
    }
}
```

I manually created the columns in the datagridview, and now I would like to populate the fields using this small method.

Comment: Are you sure there are columns available for `datagridview1` ?

Comment: What do you mean - "I manually created the columns in the datagridview"?  Do you mean you defined columns in the "Columns" property sheet of the DataGridView instance placed on a form, or do you mean you defined columns using C# code elsewhere?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 0 cells in the newly created row, that's why you are getting that exception. You cannot use statements like

```
row.Cells[0].Value = i.ToString();
```

unless you manually add cells to the blank row.

Answer (score 31):

You are just missing one line :-P

```
DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);  // this line was missing
row.Cells[0].Value = "Cell1";
row.Cells[1].Value = "Cell2";
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);
```

Comment: This answer relies on the programmer having defined columns in the DataGridView instance on a form (called 'dataGridView1').  The call to the CreateCells method relies on this definition to setup the new row's columns.  For people seeking an entirely programmatic way of defining a DataGridView, you first need to define the columns.  See SO @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524075/programatically-add-new-column-to-datagridview

Answer (score 7):

Its simple,

```
myDataGridView.Rows.Add(value1, value2, value3...);
```

It worked when I had configured my DGV previously for the coming data columns through the GUI.
So in your case, it would be like:

```
private void LoadStudentGrades(int gradeParaleloId, int subjectId)
{
    GradeStudentRepository gradeStudentRepo = new GradeStudentRepository();
    students = gradeStudentRepo.FindAllGradeStudents().Where(g => g.GradeParaleloId == gradeParaleloId).Select(g => g.Student);

    int i = 1;
    foreach (var student in students)
    {
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(i.ToString(), student.LastNameFather + " " + student.LastNameMother + ", " + student.Name);
        i++;
    }
}
```

May be you have to configure the DGV for the columns and their names separately.

Answer (score 2):

My version of this:

```
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(commandText, _oraConn);
                OracleDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                int i = 0;
                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    DataGridViewRow row = new DataGridViewRow();
                    row.CreateCells(dataGridView1);


                    row.Cells[0].Value = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
                    row.Cells[1].Value = dr.GetValue(1).ToString();
                    row.Cells[2].Value = dr.GetValue(2).ToString();
                    row.Cells[3].Value = dr.GetValue(3).ToString();
                    row.Cells[4].Value = dr.GetValue(4).ToString();
                    row.Cells[5].Value = dr.GetValue(5).ToString();

                    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

                    //MessageBox.Show( dr.GetValue("vz_id").ToString());
                    i++;
                };
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Simple version:

```
dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] { cell0Value, cell1Value });
```

My extension that I like to use:

```
static class DataGridViewExtension
{
    public static void AddCustomRow(this DataGridView dgv, object [] values, object tag = null)
    {
        int Index = dgv.Rows.Add(values);

        // Add a tag if one has been specified
        if (tag != null)
        {
            DataGridViewRow row = dgv.Rows[Index];
            row.Tag = tag;
        }
    }

    public static void AddCustomRow(this DataGridView dgv, string text, object tag = null)
    {
        AddCustomRow(dgv, new object[] { text }, tag);
    }
}
```