# How to create Datagridview in tab in loop in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, dataset

I am developing the Project where I have to read multiple CSV file and view in the DataGrid. Now here challenge is if there is 5 files I have to create 5 different tab to view in Datagrid which I am not able to do. Here is my code :

```
       DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        foreach (String file in openFileDialogCSVFilePath.FileNames)
        {
            string fileLocation = file;
            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(@fileLocation);
            CsvReader reader = new CsvReader(fileLocation);
            ds = reader.RowEnumerator;
        }
        dGridCSVdata.DataSource = ds;
        dGridCSVdata.DataMember = "The Data";
```

Can anybody help me how I can accomplish this? Thanks in advance.

UPDATE:

I want to create Tab pro grammatically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I manually add data to a dataGridView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6092463/how-can-i-manually-add-data-to-a-datagridview)

Comment: @Anas I have already tried that, It didnt  worked in my case

Comment: So you have to create Tab Page programmatically and add DatagridView in each Tab based on total files available.

Comment: @SH7 Exactly. That what I am looking for.

Comment: _create 5 different tab to view in Datagrid which I am not able to do_ - You fail to tell us just what is/isn't working. Do note that stuff you do to a hidden tabpage will not automitically get updated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet . So i have a **TabControl** `tabControl1`with One TabPage.

Step 1: Read and Get total Number of Files and Store the File Path in `List<string>`

Step 2: Based on the Count of File Generate the `TabPage`.

Step 3: Read CSV File and Store it in `Datatable`

Step 4: For the `TabPage` add the `DataGridView` and map its `DataSource` to the `DataTable`

Please note that this isn't tested.

```
private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Get Total Number of File to create Total Tab
        //Pass the count in the for loop
        //Store the File Path of Each File in List<string> lstFilePath

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) //i< lstFilePath.Count
        {
            //Create Tab Programatically
            this.tabControl1.TabPages.Add("Tab Page"+ (i+1).ToString());                

            //Create DataTable to read and Store the CSV File Data
            DataTable Dt = new DataTable();

            //Based on the i value get the File Path from lstFilePath 
            //and pass it to Function below

            Dt = ConvertCSVtoDataTable("");               
            DataGridView grid = new DataGridView();
            this.tabControl1.TabPages[i].Controls.Add(grid);
            grid.DataSource = Dt;
        }
    }

    public static DataTable ConvertCSVtoDataTable(string strFilePath)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(strFilePath))
        {
            string[] headers = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
            foreach (string header in headers)
            {
                dt.Columns.Add(header);
            }
            while (!sr.EndOfStream)
            {
                string[] rows = sr.ReadLine().Split(',');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                for (int i = 0; i < headers.Length; i++)
                {
                    dr[i] = rows[i];
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

        }

        return dt;
    }
```

Comment: thank you for your response. Can you help me what is here `tabControl1`

Comment: Have edited the answer, have mentioned the steps too. The code isn't tested but i guess you could use the Part where i'm programmatically adding the `TabPage` and `DataGridView` and Populating `DataTable` from csv to `DataGridView`.