# Dynamically/programmatically adding values to DataGridView

Tags: c#, datagridview

Could anyone give a snippet of sample code for manually creating columns for DataGridView? I need to create columns with custom names and also manually select what values to show in the column cells. I have the DataGridView bound to a Collection<>

```
private void initialiseDataGridView(Part part, string batchNumber){        
    dataCollection = new DataCollection(part.name, batchNumber);
    dataCollectionSource = new BindingSource(dataCollection, null);
    serialConDataGrid.DataSource = dataCollectionSource;
    serialConDataGrid.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

    // Add columns
    DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn selectedCol = new DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn(false);
    selectedCol.HeaderText = "Selected";
    DataGridViewColumn runNumberCol = new DataGridViewColumn();
    runNumberCol.HeaderText = "Run Number";
    serialConDataGrid.Columns.Clear();
    serialConDataGrid.Columns.Add(selectedCol);
    serialConDataGrid.Columns.Add(runNumberCol);

    // How can I specify which values to populate into the column cells here?
}
```

[This msdn sample seems to be empty.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180996(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple example on how to do it.

Here is the class of objects you want to display in the `DataGridView`. The things you want to display needs to be properties:

```
public class Fruit
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Color Color { get; set; }

    public Fruit(string name, Color color)
    {
        Name = name;
        Color = color;
    }
}
```

And here is the code for binding this data to the `DataGridView`. You need to link the name of the property to the `dataGridViewColumn.DataPropertyName` property.

```
// The list of objects
List<Fruit> fruit = new List<Fruit>( ) 
    {new Fruit("Apple",Color.Red), 
     new Fruit("Orange",Color.Orange), 
     new Fruit("Pear",Color.Green)}; 

BindingSource source = new BindingSource(fruit, null);

dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn column = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
column.HeaderText = "Name Of Fruit";
column.DataPropertyName = "Name"; // Name of the property in Fruit
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(column);

DataGridViewTextBoxColumn colorColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
colorColumn.HeaderText = "Color";
colorColumn.DataPropertyName = "Color"; // Name of the property in Fruit
dataGridView1.Columns.Add(colorColumn);

dataGridView1.DataSource = source;
```

Comment: Thank you, that was a great help. Could you take a look at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25185735/set-datagridtextboxcolumn-dataproperty-to-a-member-of-an-array-c-sharp Basically I want to figure out how to set the DataPropertyName to an element of an array.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

[Programatically-add-new-column-to-datagridview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524075/programatically-add-new-column-to-datagridview#answer-5524129)

The columns need "DataPropertyName" Property to bind to field name.

[DataGridViewTextBoxColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewtextboxcolumn(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I've tried to set the DataPropertyName in my application but it does not display the data from those fields. btw your first link is pointing to an msdn page