# Adding "column" to dataview, datarow, list or?

Tags: c#, winforms, dataview

I'm working with **winforms** and hit a problem.

I have some data in sql and one of the columns is a sql generated unix timestamp.
The sql is updating itself, so I can´t change the data in the datatable.

So i'm populating the datatable and then i use this ("to get the newest items"):
    `DataView dv = db.historyDataSet.Tables["historyTable"].AsEnumerable().Where(r    => (Convert.ToInt64(r["timestamp"])) > (time)).AsDataView();`

This generates my dataview, and from that I want to simply populate a dataGridWiew by:
    `dataGridView.DataSource = dv;`
But how do I get the datagridview to show human readable time (I am using a function for that called timeConvert - the conversion is not my problem)

I do this:

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in batchvisGridView.Rows)
{
DataRow dr = ((DataRowView)row.DataBoundItem).Row;
dr["timestamp"] = timeConvert(Convert.ToInt64(dr["timestamp"]));
}
```

But I get an **error** that says I cant store the string in the cell because it has a different type:
Additional information: *Inputstring was not in correct format.<10:35 26/03-16> couldn' t be saved in timestamp. Expected type is Int32.*

How do I do this the best way? (and I don' t want to change database)

Comment: I hope this can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524075/programatically-add-new-column-to-datagridview

Comment: I suggest making a backup of the original data table and use a different dataview for displaying in the user interface so you're only concern would be changing the datetime format of the timestamp column values

Comment: What's the data type for `timestamp` column in database table? What's the type of the column in your datatable?

Comment: Timestamp is Int64 in dataTable and sql. But when converted to human readable its a string.

Comment: You don't need to add any other column to the `DataTable`. You can use [`CellFormatting`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting(v=vs.110).aspx) event of grid to format `Int64` value and show it as `DateTime`