# Why do I have a " Value of type String cannot be converted to DataGridViewColumn error?

Tags: c#

I am trying to add columns from a combobox input to a datagridview column. I have:

```
me.DatagridView1.Columns.Add(Combobox1.text)
```

but I am getting an error stated in the title. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The columns collection cal only store DataGridViewColumns not text

Comment: I'd imagine `Columns.Add( ... )` wants you to put a *column* there, not a `string`.

Comment: how about replacing the name of an existing column to a text from a combobox, does that work?

Comment: Reference this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27844026/2252962

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the [documentation for `DataGridViewColumnCollection.Add` method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3f7a54z8(v=vs.110).aspx), you'll see there's an override that takes two strings, one which represents the column name, and the other that represents the display text.

So you should be able to do:

```
me.DatagridView1.Columns.Add(Combobox1.text, Combobox1.text)
```

(or use some other value for the header text if you wish)

Comment: You're welcome. When in doubt, hover over the method name in visual studio and you should be able to see the overloads for the method and what the parameters are for. If that doesn't help, go to google and search for your keywords, like "datagridview columns add", and add "C#" to the keywords. almost always gets you the documentation.

Comment: will do. Thank you very much!