# How to add columns to an already existing ultragrid?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, windows-forms-designer, infragistics

I've got an ultragrid already filled with properties. Now if some properties changed overtime i want to show the initially properties and the new ones in a column next to them. I looked on the official infragistics site and on stackoverflow, but there were only ways how to create a complete new ultragrid without designer. I appreciate any help in c# or vb.net.

Comment: Possibly: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5524129/13108684

Comment: But do you want to create new columns (and set the position) programmatically o in design-mode?

Comment: @Marco I want to create new columns programmatically. I just made new properties now which inherit from the class which is the datasource. To get the columns in the right order i used ' e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("Leistungscode").Header.VisiblePosition = 0
        e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("K_Art").Header.VisiblePosition = 1
        e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("K_ArtCompare").Header.VisiblePosition = 2

Comment: I confirm that is the way. Are there other problems?

Answer (score 0):

```
e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("[Column Name 1]").Header.VisiblePosition = 0

e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("[Column Name 2]").Header.VisiblePosition = 1

e.Layout.Bands(0).Columns("[Column Name 3]").Header.VisiblePosition = 2
```